# Non-conformable arrays when Subsetting array

Tags: arrays, r, subset, netcdf

I have been working on Netcdf file. I extracted variable time, lon, lat and Chlorophyl, and I made an array. It has 130   51 4716 dimension. I want to make a subset for a certain region so I can easily do some correlation with it. 
I have been struggling and looking for alternative codes but it keeps telling me this error:

> Error in lon <= -5.14 & lon >= -4.14 & lat >= 34.86 : non-conformable arrays

Here is my code:

```
ch-exp1<- subset(chl.array, lon <= -5.14 & lon >= -4.14 & lat >= 34.86 & lat <= 35.86)
```

Comment: What programing language is this?

Comment: R language,    I also tried this code but doesnt give me what I want it`s just ignore the lat and lon I spicified and keep all the others,                  Mlon1<--5.14
Mlon2<--4.14
Mlat1<-35.86
Mlat2<-34.86
Mlat=({35:36})
Mlon=lon[{-4.786:-6}]
ch-exp1=chl.array[Mlat,Mlon,]